# free archipack add on

Tags: archipack-add-on

I have never used Archipack add-on before. When ever I try to add any element (window, door, stair, fence..) aside from wall, from the add mesh menu. A blank window appears on the screen and I can not add anything from the addon apart from a wall.

[image]

I am doing something wrong? How can I add element from the free Archipack add-on for Blender?

Comment: just a guess: In the preferences dialog where you activate the add-on, there is a "render presets thumbs" button from the add-on. Have you pressed it?

Comment: @Blunder Now I did it. Thanks! It worked!